# How to disable activation email to specific user role?

Tags: user-roles, wp-mail

I'm using Ultimate Member to manage my user roles. I have the Activation Emails active and it sends to new subscribers as expected. But when a user with role "Employee" subscribes, I don't want them to get this activation email.

Right now someone with the role "Employee" is getting two emails, the one I want and the extra activation one.

Is there a way to deactivate the activation email for a specific user role?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate member is truly magical, although it is a little difficult to comprehend. If you wish to prevent certain user role notifications, utilise the ultimate member hook from the link below.

Ultimate Members Hooks
https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1324-hooks-list?hook=um_email_notifications

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).